# How to use ng-bind-html but disable tag <h1>, <b>... AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html

I used ng-bind-html and show success data, but I want to show only text, not show data with style ,  because it ruined my layout:

[image]

Data is content's notes: `<h1>some text....</h1>`

My filter:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myModule", []);
myApp.filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
    return function (text) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    };
}]);
```

My view:

```
<p ng-bind-html="note.content.substr(0, 130) + '...' | to_trusted"></p>
```

Comment: You really shouldn't arbitrarily trust content sent from other sites unless you are filtering it out to make sure it doesn't have malicious scripts being sent into your program.  Not sure about stripping out the html tags client side but server side could use unfluff https://github.com/ageitgey/node-unfluff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You can apply a css class to the div, resetting html tag formatting behavior overriding it. For example:

```
<p class="ignore-html-tags" ng-bind-html="note.content.substr(0, 130) + '...' | to_trusted"></p
```

And in your css:

```
.ignore-html-tags * {
  font-size: 10px !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  /* any other style overwrite */
}
```

Comment: It's not working :(.
Html: <p class="ignore-html-tags"><h1>aaa</h1></p. style of class ignore-html-tags not work with <h1>
Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/lion5893/2t5q0fhc/

Comment: @NamLêQuý could you please post a jsfiddle or a codepen snippet? I'll help you directly on the code, then

Comment: thanks your help, i fixed. i use .ignore-html-tags * {...}